# How to export data from Drupal to RoR?

Tags: database, drupal, export

How `entity_id`, `node_id` and `user_id` associated with each other in Drupal? So that I can export the data! I tried associating `entity_id=node_id`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users, node and taxonomy terms are all entities. So they all have entity IDs.

- A users entity id is called **uid**, or User ID.
- A nodes entity id is called **nid**, or Node ID.
- A taxonomy terms entity id is called **tid**, or Term ID.

So `entity_id == node_id` IF `entity type == "node"`